# Handling Balance in Customer Ledger

Tags: php, mysql, accounting

I am creating customer ledger in php and mysql. Below is the way in which i am creating this.

First of all an entry added and saved in database. Entry in database is given below.

[image]

Entry to the user side is given below.

[image]

Now another entry added to the Database. Database view is given below for new entry.
[image]

User view for another entry is given below.

[image]

Now i added the 5$ amount against the invoice number 1. which looks like in database like below.

[image]

and on the user side its look like this.

[image]

**Problem:**

Upto this point everything is correct. but now i want to update the **invoice 1** after updating invoice 1 its look like this.

In this editing i add the 30$ amount more to the invoice 1 and now its total become 45$ + 30$ = 75$ You can see it in following pic. and update this into the database. its debit becomes 75$ and balance also 75$.

[image]

Now it should show the 105$ balance in second row against invoice 4. because 75$ for first entry and 30$ for second entry so total balance should be 105. and 5$ amount is also paid. so final balance should be 100$.

**How to handle this balance?  i am doing it on right track or i have to do something. please guide me about this that how to handle balance in customer ledger ?**

Comment: You don't need debit and credit columns if you have amount and type.

Comment: @P.Salmon i want to show debit and credit on user side...

Comment: @P.Salmon but problem is when i edit invoice or add payment against any invoice. ..balance column will be disturb

Comment: It will also be disturbed if you delete correct an 'old' transaction - best in my view not to store columns which can be calculated and live with the (Slight) overhead.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes it will also disturbed, but i don't provide delete option to user for deleting invoice. if invoice is incorrect he can edit it, but can't delete. So i know proper way how can i handle the balance column?